# How to find the datetime difference between rows in a column, based on the condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
date        time       val1
2018-12-31  09:00:00   15
2018-12-31  10:00:00   22
2018-12-31  11:00:00   19
2018-12-31  11:30:00   10
2018-12-31  11:45:00   5
2018-12-31  12:00:00   1
2018-12-31  12:05:00   6
```

I want to find how many minutes are between the `val1` value that is greater than 20 and the `val1` value that is lower than or equal to 5?

In this example, the answer is 1 hour and 45 minutes = 95 minutes.

I know how to check the difference between two datetime values:

```
(df.from_datetime-df.to_datetime).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

But how to slice it over the DataFrame, detecting the proper rows?

Comment: What about the value 1, it's also lower than 5, shouldnt you calculate the difference for that?

Comment: @Erfan: No, only the first row that fitted this condition should be selected. In this case, if we move from top of the DataFrame to the end, the first row in which `val1` is lower or equal to 5 is at 11:45:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: Taking into consideration that date might be different**

Convert the date column to a `datetime` object and time column to a `timedelta` object and combine them to get another `datetime` object

```
df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['date_time'] = df['date'] + df['time']

df

          date      time    val1              date_time
0   2018-12-31  09:00:00      15    2018-12-31 09:00:00
1   2018-12-31  10:00:00      22    2018-12-31 10:00:00
2   2018-12-31  11:00:00      19    2018-12-31 11:00:00
3   2018-12-31  11:30:00      10    2018-12-31 11:30:00
4   2018-12-31  11:45:00       5    2018-12-31 11:45:00
5   2018-12-31  12:00:00       1    2018-12-31 12:00:00
6   2018-12-31  12:05:00       6    2018-12-31 12:05:00
```

Now could use one of these two methods

1) Love lambdas and this works with Series objects.

```
subtr = lambda d1, d2: abs(d1 - d2)/np.timedelta64(1, 'm')

d20 = df[df.val1 > 20].date_time.iloc[0]
d5 = df[df.val1 <= 5].date_time.iloc[0]
subtr(d20, d5)

105.0
```

2) Needs DataFrame object instead of Series object. Hinders with my aesthetics

```
d20 = df[df.val1 <= 5][['date_time']].iloc[0]
d5 = df[df.val1 > 20][['date_time']].iloc[0]

abs(d5 - d20).astype('timedelta64[m]')[0]

105.0
```

Comment: Thanks. but what if the day is different?

Comment: I got the error `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`.

Comment: Also I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the errors you get here. Could be because I started out with a `string` object for the date and time columns.

Comment: Yes, probably that's the case. In line `abs(lower - upper).astype('timedelta64[m]')[0]` I get the error `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: It has something to do with how you have defined `upper` and `lower` because they are supposed to be `Series` objects

Comment: But can you use `date_time` please, that you create, instead of simply `time`?

Answer (score 0):

So this is my approach:

1) Filter out any val1 that is not >= 20 or <= 5

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018-12-31','2018-12-31','2018-12-31','2018-12-31','2018-12-31','2018-12-31','2018-12-31'],
                  'time':['09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '11:30:00', '11:45:00', '12:00:00', '12:05:00'],
                  'val1': [15,22,19,10,5,1,6]})

df2 = df[(df['val1'] >= 20)|(df['val1'] <= 5)].copy()
```

Then we will do the following code:

```
df2['TimeDiff'] = np.where(df2['val1'] - df2['val1'].shift(-1) >= 15, 
                           df2['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]').shift(-1) - df2['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]'), 
                           np.NaN)
```

Let me go through this.

`np.where` is a if statement, where if the first statment is true it will do the second, if not true then the third.

`df2['val1'] - df2['val1'].shift(-1) >= 15` Since we filtered the df the minimum difference between two rows must be great than or equal to 15.

If it is true:

`df2['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]').shift(-1) - df2['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')` We take the later time and subtract it from the beginning time.

If not true, we just return `np.NaN`

We get a df that looks like the following:

```
       date       time     val1   TimeDiff
1   2018-12-31  10:00:00    22    01:45:00
4   2018-12-31  11:45:00     5      NaT
5   2018-12-31  12:00:00     1      NaT
```

If you want to put the TimeDiff on the end time you can do the following:

```
df2['TimeDiff'] = np.where(df2['val1'] - df2['val1'].shift(1) <= -15, 
                           df2['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]') - df2['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]').shift(), 
                           np.NaN)
```

and you will get:

```
       date        time    val1   TimeDiff
1   2018-12-31  10:00:00    22      NaT
4   2018-12-31  11:45:00     5    01:45:00
5   2018-12-31  12:00:00     1      NaT
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get minutes as the output, not the DataFrame. Could you please update your solution?